# Curved milky way image

Tags: photography, milky-way

In today's microsoft bing https://www.bing.com/ background image the milky way is seen as curved. How is this possible?

Comment: BTW, if that answer didn't entirely clarify things, maybe seeing the same phenomenon in a different context could help; look at [this](https://www.alamy.com/bangkok-city-360-panorama-nana-and-sukhumvit-road-aerial-photography-image154610703.html?imageid=09D95C9D-37EF-40AE-B7F3-1B4FC5BFB8D9&p=283051&pn=1&searchId=d5926e3dd1836fa5e5cea7331c92ddee&searchtype=0) 360deg panoramic image of a city - the (straight) streets appear curved as a consequence of mapping the spherical panorama onto a flat, rectangular image.